# How to create a density plot of all data overlaid with a density plot of a subset of the data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that appears to have a binomial distribution.

The data is a health related quality of life survey and can be subsetted according to types of training activity

I am wondering if I can overlay a density plot of the data as a whole with density plots of the training activity subsets

The data set is called `hrql.scores` and subset of the data with a particular training background is `apdj` and a second subset is `health.studio`. The test data I want to plot is the column with the heading `PCS`

I was hoping the following code would work:

```
ggplot( hrql.scores, aes( x=PCS, y=..density.. )) +
    geom_histogram(fill="cornsilk",colour="grey35",binwidth=5) +
    geom_density() + 
    geom_density( apdj, aes( x=PCS ) ) + 
    geom_density( health.studio, aes( x=PCS ))
```

But I get the error `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

How would I achieve a density plot of the total data set overlaid with the density plots of the subsets?

Comment: Probably `geom_density(data = apdj)` will work fine.

Comment: @tonytonov that was it,  thanks. If you add it as an answer I can accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page for `?geom_density` states that the first argument is `mapping`, not `data`. So the correct usage will be

```
ggplot(hrql.scores, aes(x=PCS, y=..density..)) +
    geom_histogram(fill="cornsilk", colour="grey35", binwidth=5) +
    geom_density() + 
    geom_density(data = apdj) + 
    geom_density(data = health.studio)
```

Note that there is no need for additional `aes` mapping, since it is inherited from the top `ggplot` call.